# Too much page load time of java application server when the server is not being used

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, keep-alive

I have a java web application which contains simple 3 jsps.

My jsp shows only one image (jpg)  and there is a "NEXT" button. If it is clicked, same jsp is reloaded and shows another image.

I noticed that if I click the next button with the period of 1-2 seconds the page load is very normal (50-60 msec). However, if I wait 8-10 seconds it suddenly freezes and responses too late, even 6-7 seconds !

The pages are used only by me. There is no other traffic on.

Here is my keep-alive settings at run time :

```
KeepAliveInfo:
--------------------
KeepAliveCount        0/512
KeepAliveHits         132
KeepAliveFlushes      0
KeepAliveRefusals     0
KeepAliveTimeouts     8
KeepAliveTimeout      30 seconds

SessionCreationInfo:
------------------------
Active Sessions           1
Keep-Alive Sessions       0
Total Sessions Created    256/768
```

It is just a simple jsp, what might be wrong ?

--EDIT (Test SS has been added)

[image]

Comment: You could try the developer tool of [chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/resource-loading#resource-network-timing) or firefox and see which part of loading taking the majority time first.

Comment: I already tested with the firebug. I edited the answer. But it can change, sometimes the JPG takes so much time to load even it is just 10kb.